# Is there an AWS worker environment for Localstack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, localstack

I have just started to use [Localstack](https://github.com/localstack) to locally test our application which uses AWS SQS service.
AWS makes available also another service which is strictly coupled with SQS which are the so-called [Worker environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html), which gives you a sort of automatic consumer of the SQS queues. 
The question is: is there a similar facility in localstack?
 Or maybe in other, similar, projects
?
 I've searched but haven't found yet what I am looking for ..
Thanks in advance
Bye